# How to use ngx-mat-intl-tel-input for creating input with country flag

Tags: angular, input, angular-material

No proper styling of the input and the input type is hidden and only when I click on the window I could see the popup window for selecting countries.

Could someone help me in styling the element?

I have did the following and there is no errors but the expected output is not 
in correct style. I could see any input text for inputting phone number.

1. I have installed and imported the module in my app.module.ts

   ```
         import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
            import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
           import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
         import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
               browser/animations';
        import { NgxMatIntlTelInputModule  } from "ngx-mat-intl-tel-input";
        import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import { MaterialModule } from "./material/material.module";

               @NgModule({
             declarations: [
               AppComponent
             ],
             imports: [
               BrowserModule,
               BrowserAnimationsModule,

               FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
               NgxMatIntlTelInputModule ,
               MaterialModule
             ],
             providers: [],
             bootstrap: [AppComponent]
           })
           export class AppModule { }
   ```
2. create formgroup in my app.component.ts.

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormArray,FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

     phoneForm = new FormGroup({
       phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required)

    });


     ngOnInit() {
       // initialization logic goes here

     }

   }
   ```
3. add the following snippet in my app.component.html-template

   ```
       <form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
        <div>
         <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input style="border: 2px solid red; padding: 10px;margin-left: 100px;width: 100px; height: 100px;"
           [preferredCountries]="['us', 'gb']"

           [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
           [enablePlaceholder]="true"
           name="phone"
           formControlName="phone" #phone></ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
         <mat-hint>e.g. {{phone.selectedCountry.placeHolder}}</mat-hint>
         <mat-error *ngIf="f.form.controls['phone']?.errors?.required">Required Field</mat-error>
         <mat-error *ngIf="f.form.controls['phone']?.errors?.validatePhoneNumber">Invalid Number</mat-error>
        </div>
       </form>
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Considering you have this in your html component

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                        <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input
                        [preferredCountries]="['us', 'gb']"
                        [enablePlaceholder]="true"
                        [enableSearch]="true" name="phone" #phone>
                      </ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
```

you need to add css to make the country dropdown visible. Initially when the component loads, the country dropdown has an opacity of 0 so you need to override that by **adding opacity as 1!important.**

[image]

For alignment, I have added 8px bottom positioning

```
.country-selector{
  opacity:1 !important;
  bottom:8px !important;
}
```

Aligning phone input field with the country dropdown

```
input:not(.country-search){
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

The country dropdown takes the entire window height so I have made the max-height as 250px and font-size to 0.8rem

```
 .mat-menu-content:not(:empty){
  max-height:250px;
}


.country-list-button{
  font-size: 0.8rem!important;
}
```

[image]

Here is the stackblitz project for the same : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input-demo

Comment: Can you please share a example for this on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @SushilKumarGupta I have updated the answer with an example link. Check it out

Comment: @Sitaram great answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually. the  opacity:1 !important; causes a bug. It makes the country flag appear even when the field is not clicked.. Just remove that and everything else is 100%